# How to identify unused PPAs?

Tags: apt, ppa

Let's say I want to verify if some PPAs aren't being used so I can minimize conflicts or whatever else could happen. Is it possible to verify which PPAs are no longer in use?

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use Ubuntu Software Center. Open it and use the arrow down next to "installed". It will list (from bottom up) PPA's installed:

[image]

When you click on a PPA (TLP as an example) it will list the software included in this PPA. A green 'tick' means the software is installed. If none are the PPA is unused.

[image]